# Question about integral of the product of two continuous functions.

Tags: analysis, continuity, calculus-of-variations

I'm having a hard time understanding why the following lemma is true:

> If a $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and if 
>   $$\int_a^b f(x)g(x) \,dx = 0 $$
>   for every function $g(x)$ continuous on $[a,b]$ such that $g(a) = g(b) = 0$, then $f(x) = 0$ for all $[a,b]$.

Now lets say $f(x) = 5$ and $g(x) = \sin(x)$, then $  \displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)g(x)\, dx = 0 $, both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous $[0,  2\pi ]$, but $f(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: The lemma says the condition must hold for all $g(x)$. In your example you tried with only one possible $g(x)$. But what about if you put $g(x)=x(x-2\pi)$? If the integral is not zero for this other $g(x)$ the lemma doesn't give you that $f(x)=0$.

Comment: The idea is that if $f$ pokes up away from zero anywhere, you can find a $g$ that highlights this part of $f$ and wipes out the rest, so that there's nothing left to make a net zero upon integrating.

Comment: @MPW You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the *"for every continuous function $g(x)$"*.

You take any continuous function $g$ (such that $g(a) = g(b) = 0$). Compute the integral, and find that it is zero! Now you need to show that this implies $f$ is the constant function $0$.

In your example, Pp gave an example of $g$ where $f(x) = 5$ gives a non-zero integral.

Comment: Am I reading this wrong? 

The lemma claims that $f(x)=0$ for every $g(x)$. But I found a $g(x)$ where $f(x)$ doesn't have to be $0$ (it can be any constant). It appears to me as if, in this example, the hypothesis of the lemma is true, but the conclusion isn't.

Comment: @DanielVaca: It says, if $f$ is such that, for any $g$ (picked by anyone, not just you or me), the integral is $0$. Then $f$ has to be $0$.

Comment: Note that $f$ is fixed as $g$ is variated in the collection of all continuous functions with $g(a) = g(b) = 0$. For a fixed $f$, you are not supposed to check the condition with a particular $g$ but all $g$ satisfying the condition.